# PHP - Combining 2 Queries to 1 Result Output

Tags: php, sql, arrays, join

I have a database with 2 tables. one called "object" and the other called "object_meta".

now i want to save additional fields depending to an entry in the "object" table inside the "object_meta" table. until now i do so with 2 queries.

1st query:

```
SELECT * FROM object WHERE id=$id
```

and the 2nd query:

```
SELECT * FROM object_meta WHERE object_id=$id
```

and then i put this 2nd query inside a new field of the 1st array called ex: meta_fields
 including the array of the query to "object_meta"

```
$array[$id]['additional_fields'][$add_field[key]] = $add_field[value];
```

please can someone show me how to do this with a join?

thx a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT     object.*, object_meta.*
FROM       object
INNER JOIN object_meta
ON         object.id = object_meta.object_id
WHERE      object.id = ?
```

Adjust the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` if `object_meta` does not carry information for every object. The fields of `object_meta` will then be `NULL` if there is no matching row.

Note that this will not put the values into `addtional_fields`, but on the same level as all the other values.

Comment: ok yeah it seems this work fine but can i exclude the "object_id"-field from the "object_meta"-table in the output array?

Comment: oh no, it doesnt work. it puts the keys and values from the "object_meta" table after the "object"-table array but as key => key, value => value - not as key => value

Comment: @user3421973 Show off your code then. The query itself is fine (you can check in PHPmyAdmin.)

Comment: Ok in the first table (object) i have for example 3 fields (id, type, admin) and in the other table i have also 3 fields (object_id,key,value) to store a unlimited number of fields to each object.
the stuff from the "object_meta"-table depends on the field "object_id" which links to the object in "object"-table. i will combine all the fields to output 1 array with all fields like 
( id:1 , type:post , admain:admin, ) and the additional fields from the "object-meta"-table like ( additional_field_key:additional_field_value , additional_field_key1:additional_field_value1)

Comment: @user3421973 Looks like I misunderstood your question. This is not possible by a join then, joins are for 1:1 relations.

Comment: ok tnx is there another way to get this output without 2 queries?

Comment: @user3421973 I don't think so. If you need to fetch multiple objects use one query for the objects with `WHERE id IN(…)` and one for the meta data and then connect them in PHP. You may consider caching as well (but Caching is out of scope for this question).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it, however I would suggest to select only the required fields from both tables which you want to display and you can do as `table_name`.`col_name1`,`table_name`.`col_name2` etc and can use where condition on first table col name with the input value.

```
select * from `object`
inner join `object_meta` on `object_meta`.`object_id` = `object`.`id`
```